# Pass a search string to retrieve all contacts in Android

Tags: android, contacts

In my Android application I need to retrieve all user contacts. [just read this sample code and tutorial in developer.android.com to do so.](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) 
As this tutorial says:

> In onCreateLoader(), set up the search string pattern. To make a string into a pattern, insert "%" (percent) characters to represent a sequence of zero or more characters, or "_" (underscore) characters to represent a single character, or both. For example, the pattern "%Jefferson%" would match both "Thomas Jefferson" and "Jefferson Davis".

I can understand from above paragraph that if I need to get all contacts, I need to pass just "%" as search string. But when I pass that I get nothing. 
Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: can you please post some code

Comment: @HetalUpadhyay I didn't write any code myself for this. But you can see google tutorial code from the links I put in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not to late...

```
// Defines a variable for the search string
private val searchString: String = "_"

// Defines the array to hold values that replace the ?
private val selectionArgs = arrayOf<String>(searchString)

class ContactsFragment : Fragment(),
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    ... }
```

Then my onCreateLoader method

```
 override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
    /*
            * Makes search string into pattern and
            * stores it in the selection array
            */
    selectionArgs[0] = "%$searchString%"
... }
```

You can get sample code from [Retrieve a list of contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names)